Posix Timer timer is not accurate
I'm working on vxWorks 7. I've developed a class to implement POSIX timer. I'm working on a Real Time Process.
The timer is designed to run in single-shot or periodic mode.
The problem is I'm getting random timeout. I've attached a list of observed timeout against expected timeut.
Worst problem is that the same code perfectly in Linux (a non-deterministic General Purpose OS) compared to deterministic RTOS.
Source Code :
posix_timer.hpp
#pragma once


#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>



typedef int signal_t;

static const std::int64_t getCurrentTimeInMicroseconds() 
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

class PosixTimer
{
public:

    static bool initialize(void);
    static inline const int signal_rt_min = SIGRTMIN, signal_rt_max = SIGRTMAX;

    using callback_timer_t = std::function<void(std::uint64_t)>;

    PosixTimer(callback_timer_t callback, std::uint64_t callback_data, bool periodic = false) : 
        PosixTimer(periodic)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
        this->callback_data = callback_data;
    }
    PosixTimer(bool periodic);
    PosixTimer();

    PosixTimer(const PosixTimer& instance) = delete;  //Delete copy constructor
    PosixTimer& operator=(const PosixTimer& instance) = delete; //Delete Copy Assignment 

    PosixTimer(PosixTimer&& source);
    PosixTimer& operator=(PosixTimer&& source);

    ~PosixTimer();
    bool create(void);//Create timer only
    bool create(std::uint64_t timeout, bool periodic);//Initialize the Periodic Timer Object, Create timer, set timeout and start timer
    // bool create(std::uint64_t timeout);//Create timer, set timeout and start timer
    bool update(std::uint64_t timeout);//Stop timer, update set timeout and start timer
    bool start(std::uint64_t timeout);//Set timeout and start timer
    bool start(void);//Starts the timer with the timeout value (refer private timeout variables)
    bool stop(void);//Stops the timer
    bool destroy(void);//Destroys the timer. Can't be reused without calling create
    void registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, std::uint64_t callback_data);

    static std::uint64_t in_nanoseconds(std::uint64_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_microseconds(std::uint64_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_milliseconds(std::uint32_t timeout);
    static std::uint64_t in_seconds(std::uint16_t timeout);
private:
    static inline std::map<signal_t, bool>  signal_usage_status;
    signal_t                    signal_id;
    static inline std::uint8_t  total_timer_count = 0;
    std::uint8_t                timer_count = 0;
    bool                        periodic;
    std::uint64_t               timeout;// in nano-seconds
    timer_t                     timer_id;
    sigset_t                    mask;
    std::uint64_t               callback_data;
    struct sigevent             sev;
    struct sigaction            sa;
    struct itimerspec           its;
    bool                        timer_valid {false};
    static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);
    callback_timer_t            callback;
    bool                        block_signal(void);
    bool                        unblock_signal(void);
};

class SignalNumberExhausted : public std::exception
{
private:
    static inline const std::string message = "Real-time signal number exhausted"; 
public:
    SignalNumberExhausted() {}
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};

posix_timer.cpp
#include "posix_timer.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

// The range of supported real-time signals is defined by the macros SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX.
// Programs should never refer to real-time signals using hard-coded numbers, but instead should always refer to
// real-time signals using the notation SIGRTMIN+n, and include suitable (run-time) checks that SIGRTMIN+n
// does not exceed SIGRTMAX
// the top priority RT signal is SIGRTMIN; the least (lowest) priority RT signal is SIGRTMAX.
// If different real-time signals are sent to a process, they are delivered starting with the lowest-numbered signal.
//(i.e., low-numbered signals have highest priority.)
// #define SIG          SIGRTMIN
#define CLOCK_ID CLOCK_REALTIME

bool PosixTimer::initialize(void)
{
    try
    {   
        for(int i = PosixTimer::signal_rt_min; i <= PosixTimer::signal_rt_max; i++)
        {
            // std::cout << i << std::endl;
            PosixTimer::signal_usage_status[i] = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        // Log Error
        return false;
    }
}


PosixTimer::PosixTimer()
{
     std::cout << "Inside constructor PosixTimer::PosixTimer()\n";
}


PosixTimer::PosixTimer(bool periodic)
{
    // std::cout << "Inside constructor PosixTimer::PosixTimer(bool periodic)\n";
    this->periodic = periodic;
    this->timer_count = SIGRTMIN + PosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    // NativePosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    bool signal_assigned = false;
    for (auto& [key, value]: PosixTimer::signal_usage_status)
    {
        if(value == false)//Timer not assigned
        {
            this->signal_id = key; //Assign the free signal 
            value = true;
            signal_assigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(signal_assigned == false)
    {
        // std::cout << "In PosixTimer-> If\n";
        throw SignalNumberExhausted();
    }
}

PosixTimer::PosixTimer(PosixTimer &&source)
{
    // std::cout << "Inside Move Constructor PosixTimer::PosixTimer(PosixTimer &&source)\n";
    this->timer_id = source.timer_id;
    // this->timer_valid = source.timer_valid;
    this->signal_id = source.signal_id;
    this->timer_count = source.timer_count;
    this->periodic = source.periodic;
    this->timeout = source.timeout;// in nano-seconds
    this->mask = source.mask;
    // this->callback_data = source.callback_data;
    std::exchange(this->callback_data, source.callback_data);
    this->sev = source.sev;
    this->sa = source.sa;
    this->its = source.its;
    this->callback = source.callback;
    // this->si
    //Reset source timer_id to 0 and timer validity (timer_valid) to false
    source.timer_id = 0;
    source.timer_valid = false;
    if(this->callback)
    {
         std::cout << "this->callback not empty in move constructor\n";
    }
    else
    {
         std::cout << "this->callback empty in move constructor\n";
    }

}

PosixTimer &PosixTimer::operator=(PosixTimer &&source)
{
    // std::cout << "Inside Move Assignment PosixTimer &PosixTimer::operator=(PosixTimer &&source)\n";
    if (this != &source) //performs no operation if you try to assign the object to itself
    {
        this->timer_id = source.timer_id;
        // this->timer_valid = source.timer_valid;
        this->signal_id = source.signal_id;
        this->timer_count = source.timer_count;
        this->periodic = source.periodic;
        this->timeout = source.timeout;// in nano-seconds
        this->mask = source.mask;
        // this->callback_data = source.callback_data;
        std::exchange(this->callback_data, source.callback_data);
        this->sev = source.sev;
        this->sa = source.sa;
        this->its = source.its;
        this->callback = source.callback;
        //Reset source timer_id to 0 and timer validity (timer_valid) to false
        source.timer_id = 0;
        source.timer_valid = false; 
        if(this->callback)
        {
             std::cout << "this->callback not empty in move assignment\n";
        }
        else
        {
             std::cout << "this->callback empty in move assignment\n";
        }
        
        this->sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
    }
    return *this;
}

PosixTimer::~PosixTimer()
{
    if(this->timer_valid == true)
    {
        if(this->destroy() == false)
        {
            //Log Error
        }
    }
}

bool PosixTimer::create(void)
{
    int returnValue;
    this->timer_count = SIGRTMIN + PosixTimer::total_timer_count++;
    bool signal_assigned = false;
    for (auto& [key, value]: PosixTimer::signal_usage_status)
    {
        if(value == false)//Timer not assigned
        {
            this->signal_id = key; //Assign the free signal 
            value = true;
            signal_assigned = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(signal_assigned == false)
    {
        // std::cout << "In Create-> If\n";
        throw SignalNumberExhausted();
    }
    //End of Addition by IK on 06-04-2024
    
    // Establish handler for timer signal.
    this->sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;

    sigemptyset(&this->sa.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(this->signal_id, &this->sa, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        // Log Error
        perror("sigaction in PosixCreate ");
        return false;
    }
    // Block timer signal temporarily.
    if (this->block_signal() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Create a timer
    this->sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL; // Upon timer expiration, generate the signal sigev_signo for the process.
    this->sev.sigev_signo = this->signal_id;
    this->sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
    returnValue = timer_create(CLOCK_ID, &this->sev, &this->timer_id);

    if (returnValue == -1)
    {
        // Log Error
        perror("timer_create");
        return false;
    }
    this->timer_valid = true;
    
    return true;
}


bool PosixTimer::create(std::uint64_t timeout, bool periodic)
{
    this->periodic = periodic;

    bool return_status = this->create();

    if (return_status == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this->start(timeout);
}

bool PosixTimer::update(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    // //std::cerr<<"TIMER UPDATE CALLED, Timer ID:"<<this->timer_id<<std::endl;
    bool return_status = this->stop();
    
    if (return_status == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this->start(timeout);
}

bool PosixTimer::start(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    this->its.it_value.tv_sec = timeout / 1000000000;
    this->its.it_value.tv_nsec = timeout % 1000000000;
    if (periodic == true)
    {
        this->its.it_interval.tv_sec = this->its.it_value.tv_sec;
        this->its.it_interval.tv_nsec = this->its.it_value.tv_nsec;
    }
    else
    {
        this->its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        this->its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    }
    return this->start();
}

bool PosixTimer::start(void)
{
    int return_status = timer_settime(this->timer_id, 0, &this->its, nullptr);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        perror("PosixTimer::start->timer_settime");
        return false;
    }
    
    this->unblock_signal();
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::stop(void)
{
    this->block_signal();
    struct itimerspec its;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    int return_status = timer_settime(this->timer_id, 0, &its, nullptr);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        perror("PosixTimer::stop->timer_settime");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::destroy(void)
{
    int return_status = timer_delete(this->timer_id);
    if (return_status == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        this->timer_valid = false;
        PosixTimer::signal_usage_status.at(this->signal_id) = false;
        return true;
    }
}

void PosixTimer::registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, std::uint64_t callback_data)
{
    this->callback_data = callback_data;
    this->callback = callback;
}

void PosixTimer::handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    try
    {
        PosixTimer *timer = reinterpret_cast<PosixTimer *>(si->si_value.sival_ptr);
         
        if(timer->callback)
        {
             std::cout << "timer->callback is not empty\n";
        }
        else
        {
             std::cout << "timer->callback is empty\n";
        }
        std::cerr<<"Current time in microseconds from posix timer class "<< getCurrentTimeInMicroseconds()<<std::endl; 
        timer->callback(timer->callback_data);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "PosixTimer::handler exception. " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

bool PosixTimer::block_signal(void)
{
    // Block timer signal temporarily.
#ifdef NDEBUG
    printf("Blocking signal %d\n", this->signal_id);
#endif

    // Empty a signal set
    if (sigemptyset(&this->mask) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigemptyset");
        return false;
    }
    // Add a signal to a signal set
    // std::cout << "Signal ID : " << this->signal_id << std::endl;
    if (sigaddset(&this->mask, this->signal_id) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaddset");
        return false;
    }
    // Change the signal mask of the calling thread
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &this->mask, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool PosixTimer::unblock_signal(void)
{
    // std::printf("Unblocking signal %d\n", this->signal_id);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &this->mask, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("timer start- sigprocmask");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_milliseconds(std::uint32_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000000ul;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_nanoseconds(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    return timeout;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_microseconds(std::uint64_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000ul;
}

std::uint64_t PosixTimer::in_seconds(std::uint16_t timeout)
{
    return timeout * 1000000000ul;
}

main.cpp
#include "posix_timer.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>

void handler(std::uint64_t data)
{
    try
    {
         std::cout<<"Current time: "<<getCurrentTimeInMicroseconds();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Main::handler : " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    PosixTimer::initialize();
     
    PosixTimer t;
    t.registerCallback(handler, 10);
    bool return_status = t.create(PosixTimer::in_milliseconds(1), true);
    if(return_status == true)
    {
        std::cerr << "Timer Started\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Timer Failed to Start\n";
    }
     
    
    while(1)
    {
        
    }
    return 0;
}

Time Recorded :


Why are you mixing <ctime> with <chrono>? If std::chrono is available, then you should use chrono::high_resolution_clock and high_resolution_clock::duration as timeout value. Integers are unwelcome in presence of specific data types with good abstraction. This code doesn't seem to be minimalistic; just too long for a timer. You are not using constructor initializer list. Your move constructor and assignment operator move almost every member which is the default definition and need not be coded; if a single member is missed, you're doomed. A separate class can do the default move.

Just a few notes: Your code has undefined behaviour: while(1){}. Then, the code isn't a [mcve] and the output is missing. Lastly, once you get this working, consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com.

From the documentation of VXWorks, the clock resolution is hardware-dependant, and in "many cases is 1/60th of a second".
The values that you show in your table are in increments of 1/60th of a second, matching this resolution in documentation. The values aren't random, but rather match what could be expected.

If I use The Intel Time Stamp Counter (TSC) is a 64-bit register available on Intel processors since the Pentium. Will I face the same problem?
Are their  Intel Time Coordinated Computing Tools available that can help me solve this issue? I'm using 12th Gen Tiger Lake CPU.

@DarkSorrow There should be finer time control available, it's just that the particular interface that you've chosen (POSIX Interval Timers) are documented to likely have coarse time intervals on VxWorks (in ticks which are typically 1/60 or 1/100 seconds). The copy of the VxWorks documentation that I have (in the timerLib section) mentions using nanosleep for sub-second intervals (though that's a suspend, not a callback).

Are you able to adjust the tick rate of this build of VxWorks? Ticks really are the primary timebase in the RTOS, things "happen" in increments of ticks. Something else to consider would be whether this application design is really the right way to go in this situation. I'm not sure what software you're writing, but as mentioned in the question comments, this is a lot of boilerplate code just to wrap a timer. What are the requirements that are making you go this route, but still need a very fine interval control?
